# Returning a QString from string literal

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

While writing a function with a QString return, I noticed that this works.

```
QString foo(void){
   return "foobar";
}
```

`"foobar"` isn't a QString, is a `const char *`. Why does this work without any warnings?

Comment: Types can be implicitly converted if the type being converted to has a constructor taking a single argument of the type being converted from. This is by design, which is why you don't get a warning, and most of the time it doesn't cause any troubles.

Comment: If you want disable implicit conversion (more verbose, but useful to avoid encoding issues for example), there are several macros you can define, e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII